# The function should be printed in reverse but it just gives me an error

Tags: c, string, reverse

```
#include <stdio.h>

void stringReverse( char [] );

int main()
{
    int y = 24; int x;
    char str[ 24 ] = "Print this string back.";
    //for ( x = 0; x < y; ++x )
    printf("%s \n",str);  
    stringReverse( str );
    return (0);
}

void stringReverse( char str[] )
{
    if ( str[0] == '\0' )
        return; 
    stringReverse( &str[1] );
    printf("%s \n",str[0]); 
}
```

This is basic C, so please, no complex things.  I really don't know what's wrong.

Comment: There is nothing C++ about it, so I removed the C++ tag.

Comment: @MichaelRoland: Hm.  I'm not even sure how that indentation change made it in my suggestion.  I would never fix indentation like that anyway.

Comment: You should accept Barmer's answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 7):

The format operator for printing a single char is `%c`, not `%s`. So it should be:

```
printf("%c \n",str[0]);
```

After fixing this, the output is:

```
Print this string back. 
. 
k 
c 
a 
b 

g 
n 
i 
r 
t 
s 

s 
i 
h 
t 

t 
n 
i 
r 
P
```

Comment: but the thing is it's not printing in reverse, I made this function so that it would print the sentence I gave it in reverse

Comment: Amazing to know how one of the most basic functions works? Wow. Good compilers print a warning for your code because of the type mismatch.